# Recycler View Shuffles Images On Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view, and it is being populated using Universal Image Loader.

```
@Override
public MasonryView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    MasonryView masonryView = new MasonryView(layoutView);
    //layoutView.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
    //imageLoader.destroy();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(false)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    return masonryView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MasonryView holder, int position) {

    imageLoader
            .displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    holder.donut_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.donut_progress.setProgress(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    holder.onLoadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    holder.onLoadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.donut_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                    holder.donut_progress.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                }
            });


}
```

As you can see that imageloader and the DisplayOptions are defined in the CreateView.

The Images Are displayed successfully but, when it is being scrolled the images are shuffling.

Following is my xml for custom_recycler_grid_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    !-- android:scaleType="centerCrop" --!


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onLoadImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_cross"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <progressIndicators.DonutProgress
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="1dp"
        custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="1dp"
        custom:donut_progress="50"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My Main Fragment, that has the recyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/masonry_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

However, I have also set 
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);

Comment: Post your xml code

Comment: Alright Im posting my custom_item.xml

Comment: You add the android:scrollbars="vertical" in your recycler view

Comment: Please check my recyclerview widget

Comment: One thing you must know is that RecyclerView reuses the views after every 10 views. So the position you get from the constructor is not what you are expecting to be.

Comment: That is worth notifying, thank you Atif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue completely.

The issue was with my RecyclerWidget height and width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/masonry_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I had to set my height and width to wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

Universal image Loader Async Task operation. inside Universal image loader they have used OkHTTP client server operation. that is the reason your images getting shuffled. Try to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images it is better approach. And also Go through this Example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/).

Simple and easy and faster way to load image.
Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(Datas.getRequestURL()).centerCrop().into(mStaticMap);

Comment: problem is not in the layout.

Comment: The results are even worst.

Answer (score 0):

Display the placeholder until original image loads, same problem occurred in my case also, so i followed this approach.

**Do this in your Launcher(First) activity**

// customise display options

```
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder_steve)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder_steve)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder_steve)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .build();
```

// configure

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
      /*.diskCache(lruDiskCache)*/
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Comment: I have a Circular Progress until the image is successfully loaded

Comment: @Abdul Ahad I have not tried with circular progress, but without progress it works.

Comment: initially set bitmap with drawable image, untill original image loads.                                                                                                                                                   final Bitmap thumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder_steve);

Comment: The issue remains :(
The worst thing is, it shows image flicking swapping from one place to another but eventually end up their specific location

Comment: @Abdul Ahad   inside onLoadingStarted() method, set imageview with default image holder.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap), inside onLoadingComplete() method set with original image, holder.setImageBitmap(loadedImage).

Comment: I have tried your solution but the question arises that imageloader automatically sets the image how can I set the image manually?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with

> holder.onLoadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

You have to cautious how you are setting visibility gone and then making it visible. At the end , it is the same view holder for which visibility is shown and not shown. If you ensure the

> holder.onLoadImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

at the begining of the onBindHolder() .You should be fine